# How to handle keyboard behaviour for chat screen in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

Below is the requirement for chat screen :
1.) Show last message by default when the screen comes.
2.) If I am on the last msg, and click inside message box, message box should be scrolled up and the last message should be shown above this box. Header shouldn't be gone. 
3.) If I m in between the chat messages, and click inside message box, then only message box should be above side of keyboard, not the message list. Please keep in mind that header should be visible in all cases. Header is a RelativeLayout.

**Below are some of the screens required to analyze the requirement :**

[image: Chat screen and "nd" is last message]

[image: Last message scrolls but header is not visible]

Here is some portion of code I am doing to handle softkeypad behaviour:

Here is the code related to :
This is the code for sendbox OnClick :

```
case R.id.editEmojicon : {

                if (messagesItems != null && messagesItems.size() > 0) {
                    currentMessageID = adapter.getCurrentMessageID();
                    lastMessageID = messagesItems.get(messagesItems.size() - 1).getMessageId();

                    if (lastMessageID.equalsIgnoreCase(currentMessageID))// i.e. We are on last message so scroll screen to last and last should be upside of message box
                    {
                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
                    } else // We are not on last message so don't scroll the screen
                    {
                        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
                    }
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: Same problem..did you get solution for this..?

Answer (score 0):

You should align your header to the top, align your chat bar (with the edit text) to the bottom, and set layout_above and layout_below to your scroll view, like the following:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    ...
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/header"
            >

      ...
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/chat_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        >
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/chat_bar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

hope that helps.

Edit :
For the scroll behaviour you can store the last item displayed in the listView ScrollListener

```
 mList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                lastItemPosition = firstVisibleItem+visibleItemCount;
            }
        });
```

and then set back the last item by scrolling to hist position when the keyboard is displayed

```
 mList.setSelectionFromTop(mLastItemPosition, mList.getHeight()-   mList.setSelectionFromTop(mLastItemPosition, mList.getHeight()-  mList.getAdapter().getView(mLastItemPosition,null,mList).getHeight());
```

Comment: 1.) I have a RelativeLayout, Inside this.. I have a header  at top in a layout, send box and send button at bottom in another layout, and ListView in between both the layouts.

Comment: as long as your header and your ListView and your send box are inside a RelativeLayout, this should do the trick. Keeping header on top with android:layout_alignParentTop="true" , keeping sendbox on bottom with android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and your List in the middle with     android:layout_above="@+id/chat_bar"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"

Comment: then for the keyboard behaviour you can use https://gist.github.com/felHR85/6070f643d25f5a0b3674 and do stuff like scroll the list when the keyboard is displayed( or not if the list isnt scrolled to the bottom ).

Comment: Maybe you should post your code, it will be easier for me to help you.

Comment: I appreciate you are taking interest, please check.. I have update the question.

Answer (score 0):

It actually turns out to be very easy to implement. When you use listView for your list, add these lines after the initialisation:

```
lv_chat.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_NORMAL);
lv_chat.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

where `lv_chat` is your ListView object!

The first line makes sure that when new data comes in, it will automatically scroll to bottom.

The second lines forces the list view to be drawn from bottom.

All your requirements will be covered in these.

This is a helper method to peacefully scrollDown your list, in case you are trying to explicitly scrollDown:

```
public void scrollDown() {
    lv_chat.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lv_chat.setSelection(chatListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Hope it helps! :)